# Add new column to Pandas dataframe using conditional values from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add a new column `retailer_relationship`, to my dataframe.

I would like each row value of this new column to be `'TRUE'` if the `retailer` column value starts with any items within the list `retailer_relationship`, and `'FALSE'` otherwise.

What I've tried:

```
list_of_relationships = ("retailer1","retailer2","retailer3")

for i in df.index:
    for relationship in list_of_relationships:            
        if df.iloc[i]['retailer'].str.startswith(relationship):
            df.at[i, 'retailer_relationship'] = "TRUE"
        else:
            df.at[i, 'retailer_relationship'] = "FALSE"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression combining the `^` special character, which specifies the beginning of the string, with another regex matching every element of `retailer_relationship`, since `startswith` does not accept regexes:

```
import re

regex = re.compile('^' + '|'.join(list_of_relationships))

df['retailer_relationship'] = df['retailer'].str.contains(regex).map({True: 'TRUE', False: 'FALSE'})
```

Since you want the literal strings `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'`, we can then use `map` to convert the booleans to strings.

An alternative method that is *slightly* faster, though I don't think that'll matter:

```
df['retailer_relationship'] = df['retailer'].str.contains(regex).transform(str).str.upper()
```

Comment: I'm getting:
TypeError: can only join an iterable (on the regex line)

Comment: @Deskjokey Did you run `retailer_relationship = ("retailer1","retailer2","retailer3")` before that? Actually, why do you call it `retailer_relationship` when you iterate through `list_of_relationships`?

Comment: It works. Just had to change: regex = re.compile('^' + '|'.join(list_of_relationships))

Comment: @Deskjokey Yup, I wrote my answer based on the original question. I suggest you edit it to change the reference to `list_of_relationships`.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you. It would help to share a sample of your df or a dummy data representing it.

```
df.loc['retailer_relationship'] = False
df.loc[df['retailer'].isin(retailer_relationship),'retailer_relationship'] = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You still can using `startswith` in `pandas`

```
df['retailer_relationship'] = df['retailer'].str.startswith(tuple(retailer_relationship))
```